# component design in react, where to put the 'full height'?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, reagent

After using react (actually the ClojureScript wrapper reagent) for a while now, I'm still not sure what's the best way to solve the following problem:

Say you'd have a Root component:

```
class Root extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div style="display: flex">
        <div style="flex: 2 1">
          <Content></Content>
        </div>
        <div style="flex: 1 1">
          <Menu></Menu>
        </div> 
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

This separates the screen vertically into a bigger content section and a smaller menu section. I'd say this separation is clearly something the Root component should take care of. The Menu component itself might be used in another context in which the flex props don't make any sense.

```
class Menu extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div style="background-color: red">
         Buttons, etc...
      </div>
    );
  }
```

The menu however has some properties which belong definitely there: like for instance the background color. But if we run this example we'll notice that the background color does not fill the 'menu' area defined in the Root components. That's because its lacking a some height/width = "100%" style properties.

I see two ways to solve that: Either put them inside the Menu component. But this might as well not be intended in other uses of the component. If someone wants to use Menu not in it's full height it would have to be wrapped again.
Or, pass the width and height as props to the component, that's also quite some overhead...

Usually menu's are not reused that much, but this pattern arises in many other situations. What's the way to go here? Is there maybe a third way to do this?

EDIT/NOTE:

Maybe `transferPropsTo` is what I need, but I'd still leave this to discussion...

Answer (score 0):

Is the `align-items` flexbox CSS prop of any use here?

https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/#article-header-id-7